# Why doesn't byte[] b = new byte[8](); work?

Tags: c#, arrays

I already know that `byte[] b = new byte[8];` works fine. But why doesn't `byte[] b = new byte[8];` work?

For example, `byte b = new byte();` works fine, so an array style also should work but it doesn't. I have no exact idea of this reason. Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Array does not have a constructor, when you create an array you are creating a list or collection of objects, it is the objects that make up the array that will have the constructor, for example.

```
var b = new byte[8];
```

will create an array of 8 objects of type `byte` where each element of the array will be null, using constructor notation is invalid but you can use the initializer notation, eg.

```
var b = new byte[8] { new byte(), new byte(), ... };
```

Using this notation will initialize the array of 8 elements of type `byte` to a new instance of `byte`

In short `var b = new byte()` is a instantiating a variable as a `byte` and calling the constructor of the object, `var b = new byte[8]` is creating an array of *n* elements of type `byte` each initialized to null.

I hope that helps

Comment: var b = new byte[8]; does not create an array with null elements. Since byte is a value type, each element will be initialized with 0. If the array were a string or another reference type, then the slots would be initialized with null.